# How to parse Int from String.charAt()

Tags: string, parsing, char, int

I need to parse Integer from first String position.
Something like this:

```
String s = "1abc";
int x = s.charAt(0);
```

This doesn't work (obviously) but hopefully you got the idea.
I also can't use anything like this:

```
int x = s.substring(0, 1);
```

Since that would return second character ('a') in this case.

Comment: Why would it return 'a'? Extract that first letter and do an int cast and you are done. And if you are in e.g. javascript you can do a (int)s.charAt(0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For java you could do

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
```

Check if it works

Comment: Thanks, that works. I don't know why it didn't work for me before, but this is what I wanted.